# puma init.d for centos 6 fails with runuser: user /var/log/puma.log does not exist

Tags: centos, init.d

Trying to get a init.d/puma to work on Centos 6.
It throws error

```
runuser: user /var/log/puma.log does not exist
```

I run this from the /srv/books/current folder but it fails. I tried to debug the values but not quite get what is missing and why it throws this error.

```
#! /bin/sh
# puma - this script starts and stops the puma daemon
#
# chkconfig:    - 85 15
# description:  Puma
# processname:  puma
# config:       /etc/puma.conf
# pidfile:      /srv/books/current/tmp/pids/puma.pid

# Author: Darío Javier Cravero &lt;dario@exordo.com>
#
# Do NOT "set -e"

# Original script https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/tools/jungle/puma
# It was modified here by Stanislaw Pankevich <s.pankevich@gmail.com>
# to run on CentOS 5.5 boxes.
# Script works perfectly on CentOS 5: script uses its native daemon().
# Puma is being stopped/restarted by sending signals, control app is not used.

# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

# Source networking configuration.
. /etc/sysconfig/network

# Check that networking is up.
[ "$NETWORKING" = "no" ] && exit 0

# PATH should only include /usr/* if it runs after the mountnfs.sh script
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin/:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Puma rack web server"
NAME=puma
DAEMON=$NAME
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
CONFIG=/etc/puma.conf
JUNGLE=`cat $CONFIG`
RUNPUMA=/usr/local/bin/run-puma

# Skipping the following non-CentOS string
# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
# . /lib/init/vars.sh

# CentOS does not have these functions natively
log_daemon_msg() { echo "$@"; }
log_end_msg() { [ $1 -eq 0 ] && RES=OK; logger ${RES:=FAIL}; }

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) to ensure that this file is present.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

#
# Function that performs a clean up of puma.* files
#
cleanup() {
  echo "Cleaning up puma temporary files..."
  echo $1;
  PIDFILE=$1/tmp/puma/puma.pid
  STATEFILE=$1/tmp/puma/puma.state
  SOCKFILE=$1/tmp/puma/puma.sock
  rm -f $PIDFILE $STATEFILE $SOCKFILE
}

#
# Function that starts the jungle
#
do_start() {
  log_daemon_msg "=> Running the jungle..."
  for i in $JUNGLE; do
    dir=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 1`
    user=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 2`
    config_file=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 3`
    if [ "$config_file" = "" ]; then
      config_file="$dir/puma/config.rb"
    fi
    log_file=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 4`
    if [ "$log_file" = "" ]; then
      log_file="$dir/puma/puma.log"
    fi
    do_start_one $dir $user $config_file $log_file
  done
}

do_start_one() {
  PIDFILE=$1/puma/puma.pid
  if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
    PID=`cat $PIDFILE`
    # If the puma isn't running, run it, otherwise restart it.
    if [ "`ps -A -o pid= | grep -c $PID`" -eq 0 ]; then
      do_start_one_do $1 $2 $3 $4
    else
      do_restart_one $1
    fi
  else
    do_start_one_do $1 $2 $3 $4
  fi
}

do_start_one_do() {
  log_daemon_msg "--> Woke up puma $1"
  log_daemon_msg "user $2"
  log_daemon_msg "log to $4"
  cleanup $1;
  daemon --user $2 $RUNPUMA $1 $3 $4
}

#
# Function that stops the jungle
#
do_stop() {
  log_daemon_msg "=> Putting all the beasts to bed..."
  for i in $JUNGLE; do
    dir=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 1`
    do_stop_one $dir
  done
}
#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop_one() {
  log_daemon_msg "--> Stopping $1"
  PIDFILE=$1/tmp/puma/puma.pid
  STATEFILE=$1/tmp/puma/puma.state

  echo $PIDFILE

  if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
    PID=`cat $PIDFILE`
    echo "Pid:"
    echo $PID
    if [ "`ps -A -o pid= | grep -c $PID`" -eq 0 ]; then
      log_daemon_msg "---> Puma $1 isn't running."
    else
      log_daemon_msg "---> About to kill PID `cat $PIDFILE`"
      # pumactl --state $STATEFILE stop
      # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
      kill -9 $PID
    fi
    cleanup $1
  else
    log_daemon_msg "---> No puma here..."
  fi
  return 0
}

#
# Function that restarts the jungle
#
do_restart() {
  for i in $JUNGLE; do
    dir=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 1`
    do_restart_one $dir
  done
}

#
# Function that sends a SIGUSR2 to the daemon/service
#
do_restart_one() {
  PIDFILE=$1/tmp/puma/puma.pid
  i=`grep $1 $CONFIG`
  dir=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 1`

  if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
    log_daemon_msg "--> About to restart puma $1"
    # pumactl --state $dir/tmp/puma/state restart
    kill -s USR2 `cat $PIDFILE`
    # TODO Check if process exist
  else
    log_daemon_msg "--> Your puma was never playing... Let's get it out there first"
    user=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 2`
    config_file=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 3`
    if [ "$config_file" = "" ]; then
      config_file="$dir/config/puma.rb"
    fi
    log_file=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 4`
    if [ "$log_file" = "" ]; then
      log_file="$dir/log/puma.log"
    fi
    do_start_one $dir $user $config_file $log_file
  fi
return 0
}

#
# Function that statuss then jungle
#
do_status() {
  for i in $JUNGLE; do
    dir=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 1`
    do_status_one $dir
  done
}

#
# Function that sends a SIGUSR2 to the daemon/service
#
do_status_one() {
  PIDFILE=$1/tmp/puma/pid
  i=`grep $1 $CONFIG`
  dir=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 1`

  if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
    log_daemon_msg "--> About to status puma $1"
    pumactl --state $dir/tmp/puma/state stats
    # kill -s USR2 `cat $PIDFILE`
    # TODO Check if process exist
  else
    log_daemon_msg "--> $1 isn't there :(..."
  fi

  return 0
}

do_add() {
  str=""
  # App's directory
  if [ -d "$1" ]; then
    if [ "`grep -c "^$1" $CONFIG`" -eq 0 ]; then
      str=$1
    else
      echo "The app is already being managed. Remove it if you want to update its config."
      exit 1
    fi
  else
    echo "The directory $1 doesn't exist."
    exit 1
  fi
  # User to run it as
  if [ "`grep -c "^$2:" /etc/passwd`" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "The user $2 doesn't exist."
    exit 1
  else
    str="$str,$2"
  fi
  # Config file
  if [ "$3" != "" ]; then
    if [ -e $3 ]; then
      str="$str,$3"
    else
      echo "The config file $3 doesn't exist."
      exit 1
    fi
  fi
  # Log file
  if [ "$4" != "" ]; then
    str="$str,$4"
  fi

  # Add it to the jungle
  echo $str >> $CONFIG
  log_daemon_msg "Added a Puma to the jungle: $str. You still have to start it though."
}

do_remove() {
  if [ "`grep -c "^$1" $CONFIG`" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "There's no app $1 to remove."
  else
    # Stop it first.
    do_stop_one $1
    # Remove it from the config.
    sed -i "\\:^$1:d" $CONFIG
    log_daemon_msg "Removed a Puma from the jungle: $1."
  fi
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
      do_start
    else
      i=`grep $2 $CONFIG`
      dir=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 1`
      user=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 2`
      config_file=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 3`
      if [ "$config_file" = "" ]; then
        config_file="$dir/config/puma.rb"
      fi
      log_file=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 4`
      if [ "$log_file" = "" ]; then
        log_file="$dir/log/puma.log"
      fi
      do_start_one $dir $user $config_file $log_file
    fi
    case "$?" in
      0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
      2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
  ;;
  stop)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
      do_stop
    else
      i=`grep $2 $CONFIG`
      dir=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 1`
      do_stop_one $dir
    fi
    case "$?" in
      0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
      2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
  ;;
  status)
    # TODO Implement.
    log_daemon_msg "Status $DESC" "$NAME"
    if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
      do_status
    else
      i=`grep $2 $CONFIG`
      dir=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 1`
      do_status_one $dir
    fi
    case "$?" in
      0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
      2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
  ;;
  restart)
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
    if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
      do_restart
    else
      i=`grep $2 $CONFIG`
      dir=`echo $i | cut -d , -f 1`
      do_restart_one $dir
    fi
    case "$?" in
      0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
      2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
  ;;
  add)
    if [ "$#" -lt 3 ]; then
      echo "Please, specifiy the app's directory and the user that will run it at least."
      echo "  Usage: $SCRIPTNAME add /path/to/app user /path/to/app/config/puma.rb /path/to/app/config/log/puma.log"
      echo "    config and log are optionals."
      exit 1
    else
      do_add $2 $3 $4 $5
    fi
    case "$?" in
      0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
      2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
  ;;
  remove)
    if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]; then
      echo "Please, specifiy the app's directory to remove."
      exit 1
    else
      do_remove $2
    fi
    case "$?" in
      0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
      2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
  ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage:" >&2
    echo "  Run the jungle: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart}" >&2
    echo "  Add a Puma: $SCRIPTNAME add /path/to/app user /path/to/app/config/puma.rb /path/to/app/config/log/puma.log"
    echo "    config and log are optionals."
    echo "  Remove a Puma: $SCRIPTNAME remove /path/to/app"
    echo "  On a Puma: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart} PUMA-NAME" >&2
    exit 3
  ;;
esac
:
```

puma.conf

```
# /etc/init/puma.conf - Puma config

# This example config should work with Ubuntu 12.04+.  It
# allows you to manage multiple Puma instances with
# Upstart, Ubuntu's native service management tool.
#
# See workers.conf for how to manage all Puma instances at once.
#
# Save this config as /etc/init/puma.conf then manage puma with:
#   sudo start puma app=PATH_TO_APP
#   sudo stop puma app=PATH_TO_APP
#   sudo status puma app=PATH_TO_APP
#
# or use the service command:
#   sudo service puma {start,stop,restart,status}
#

description "Puma Background Worker"

# no "start on", we don't want to automatically start
stop on (stopping puma-manager or runlevel [06])

# change apps to match your deployment user if you want to use this as a less privileged user (recommended!)
setuid deploy
setgid deploy

respawn
respawn limit 3 30

instance ${app}

script
# this script runs in /bin/sh by default
# respawn as bash so we can source in rbenv/rvm
# quoted heredoc to tell /bin/sh not to interpret
# variables
exec /bin/bash <<'EOT'
  # set HOME to the setuid user's home, there doesn't seem to be a better, portable way
  export HOME="$(eval echo ~$(id -un))"

  cd $app

  if [ -d "$HOME/.rbenv/bin" ]; then
    export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
  elif [ -f  /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh ]; then
    source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
  elif [ -f /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm ]; then
    source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
  elif [ -f "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]; then
    source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
  elif [ -f /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh ]; then
    source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh
    if [ -f /usr/local/share/chruby/auto.sh ]; then
      source /usr/local/share/chruby/auto.sh
    fi
    # if you aren't using auto, set your version here
    # chruby 2.0.0
  fi

  logger -t puma "Starting server: $app"

  exec bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
EOT
end script
```

Answer (score 1):

That puma.conf should be in `/etc/init/puma.conf`, if that is in `/etc/puma.conf` it's not surprising have some issues, the init.d script is looking for a much simpler file, $JUNGLE is running cat on the file looking for a comma separated value in it.

You need to find something that isn't an Upstart file for the puma.conf .